# Webkit animation delay doesn't working with expression (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit-animation

I'm making a navbar with css and javascript and I'm getting an issue, when I put a expression in the webkit animation delay it doessn't work, but when I put a number it works.

this doesn't work:

```
link.style.webkitAnimation = "navLinkFade ease 0.5s forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s";
```

this works:

```
link.style.webkitAnimation = "navLinkFade ease 0.5s forwards 2s";
```

This animation is for the li elements of the nav and I want them to fade in one after the other.

Here's my code:

css

```
@-webkit-keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

js:

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {

        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if(link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            }
            else {
                link.style.webkitAnimation = "navLinkFade ease 0.5s forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s";
                console.log(link.style.animation);
            }
        });
    
    });
}

navSlide();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to insert a JS variable into a string use `\``. Only then you can use `${variable}`.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't even know that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using backticks (`) instead of double quotes (")

```
link.style.webkitAnimation = `navLinkFade ease 0.5s forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
```

Comment: It was that! Thank you very much! I struggled for about two days with that hahah

Answer (score -1):

Store your expression in a variable and then add it to the webkit-animation string.